# Mixing HERE content with other providers' map tiles

Tags: here-api

I am considering extending an application with HERE maps API calls (geocoding, routing, and maybe others). The application allows to select providers for different services and mix them. For example, using map tiles from one provider and showing search results from another one. I wonder, whether it is allowed to do so with HERE REST API call results. For example, show route polyline and use routing instructions from HERE and mix them with Mapbox GL tiles.

Question stems from https://legal.here.com/en-gb/terms/acceptable-use-policy, "Layering and Modifications" which seems to me prohibiting such use. In contrast, [Is it possible to use here's Maps API combined with another base map (e.g., Bing, Google, OSM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688087/is-it-possible-to-use-heres-maps-api-combined-with-another-base-map-e-g-bing) response states that it would be OK.

While I can make a separate profile that would enable HERE APIs only with HERE map tiles, I would prefer to allow users to mix providers as it is now. Currently, only HERE map tiles are supported, but those should allow me to layer other data on top, as far as I understand the allowed use terms.

In contrast to reply at Stack Overflow linked above, reply in [Knowledge Base](https://knowledge.here.com/csm_kb?id=public_kb_csm_details&number=KB0016412) states that showing geocoding results on top of other providers tiles is prohibited.